# prove $\sum \frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum \frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}$ where $x>=0$
I can show that this diverges when $x=1$ and it definitely converges when $x=0$.
However I am having trouble showing it converges otherwise(when $x$ is not $0$ and $1$).
I think I need to use the characteristic of this series that each terms is getting smaller
as $n$ greater since the bottom part grows faster. This is all I have now.

P.S. Sorry for confusion. This is first time using math notations here so I made multiple mistakes. I edited most of them.

Comment: What's the denominator? $1+x^2n$ or $1+x^{2n}$?

Comment: But $x=0$ implies sum equals 0, how can you state that diverges?

Comment: And it diverges for $x=1$ !

Comment: $\sum \frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}} < \sum \frac{x^n}{x^{2n}}$

Comment: Comparison with geometric series.

Comment: Thanks all. I don't know how to thank on comments but thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT**
Rewrite your sum as
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{x^n+x^{-n}}$$
For $x \in (0,1)$, we have
$\dfrac1{x^n+x^{-n}} < \dfrac1{x^{-n}} = x^n$.

For $x \in (1,\infty)$, we have
$\dfrac1{x^n+x^{-n}} < \dfrac1{x^{n}}$.

Comment: Perfectly make sense. Thanks a lot

Comment: For the series, do I need equality? or it is strict inequality?

Comment: @Kane If $a_n < b_n$, in general for a sequence all we can conclude is that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n$. However, if $a_n < b_n$, and the series $\sum_n a_n$ and $\sum_n b_n$ converge, then we can conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. I don't know it is proper question here but how am I supposed to study sequence and series? I studied for the exam and I am still struggling a lot. Do I need to memorize as many as possible examples?

Comment: @Kane There are only few things to memorize. All the rest you need to see how to connect to things you already know.

Comment: Ok. Again, thank you very much for the quick and right help!

Answer (score 5):

If $x\in(0,1)$, then:
$$0\leq\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}\leq \sum_{n\geq 0} x^n =\frac{1}{1-x}.$$
On the other hand, if $x>1$ then:
$$0\leq \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}\leq \sum_{n\geq 0} x^{-n} = \frac{x}{x-1},$$
so the series is converging on $\mathbb{R}^+\setminus\{1\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps a lot.

Comment: I have a question. Do I need equality? If so, can you help me understand why?